# NPN BJT used for DC Switching Load

Tags: dc-motor, bjt, npn

I am trying to learn some things for a class. This is not homework, just studying for an exma. It has to with calculating values when using a NPN BJT. I have five (only three because other 2 were not relevant) questions attached, but I really just need help with questions 1 and 2. I put my answers to the rest just incase I missed somethiing due to my misunderstanding of questions 1 and 2. Thansk in advance.

Edit: the hFE is the current gain (usually Beta, I believe)

1) ?

2) ?

3) A

4) D

5) E

[image: Question 1]

For Question 1:

I am trying to solve for R by using (parenthesis are subscript)

R = (V(OH) - V(BEsat)) / I(B)

I believe there is another voltage term that I am missing which would give.

R = (V(OH) - V(BEsat) - V(unknown)) / I(B)

I do not remember/know how to work in the current of the motor and the diode attached to the collector. I believe I(B) is equal to 10mA because that is the max that can be sourced. V(0H) and V(BEsat) are given at 4.2V and .6V, respectively. I know that there is another voltage I need to work into this, but don't see the calculation for it.

[image: Question 2]

For Question 2:

I know that from full drive mode to reduce drive mode there is a change in current, but there is NOT a change in voltage swing, V(OH). So when calculating the minimum hCE (or Current Gain / Beta), I am using

Beta = I(C) / I(B)

The value of I(B) is 2mA when maximimized as given in the problem. (Using the max value will give the minimum Beta as desired). Now for the current through the collector is I(C), but I am lost on how to get the total current using the 1A passed through the motor coil. I believe this has a lot to do with my misunderstanding of problem 1. Also, this might affect my answer in Question 3 which might be wrong since I am not understanding this Diode in parallel with the motor coil.

[image: Question 3]

Comment: It's very difficult for us to help at all if we don't know how much you know. Please show us what you've tried for the 2 questions you're unsure about.

Comment: I will do. I apologize.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too many questions in one.

Comment: Okay 1 and 2 and 3 are related. I remove the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's take these one at a time.  First question 1.

You need 1A thorough the transistor.  You have an \$h_{FE}\$ of 200.  Therefore the current into the base needs to be \$\frac{1A}{200} = 5mA\$.

The MCU outputs 4.2V.  The \$V_{BE}\$ is 0.6V. Therefore the voltage across the resistor is \$4.2 - 0.6 = 3.6V\$.

Ohms law says \$R=\frac{V}{I}\$, so \$\frac{3.6V}{0.005A} = 720\Omega\$.

Question 2. You need 1A, you have 0.002A.  Simple division:  \$\frac{1}{0.002}=500\$.

Question 3. The diode is known as a "flyback" diode, or a "diode snubber circuit".  Its purpose is to provide a path for the induced EMF when the magnetic field collapses.  So the answer for that is B since the field collapses when the power is removed.

Question 4. Yes, it prevents ESD damage. Yes, it provides galvanic isolation, so prevents ground loops. Yes, it protects from over voltage situations, so yes, it's "All of the above".

Question 5. Sorry, I can't help you there - I don't know what ABEL is.